# My derailleur completely "opened" up. It is now almost a straight line. What have i done to my derailleur?

Tags: shimano, chain, derailleur-rear

I had a flat on the side of the road.  So I took my wheel off to replace the tire with a temp to get me home.  When I reinstalled the wheel, the derailleur "opened up" completely...what have I done/forgot to do? Can I fix it or is it done?

[image]

Comment: I find it unlikely that you would have accidentally adjusted the "B tension" screw or that it could even cause such a large adjustment. Have you checked if there is a broken spring in the derailleur?

Comment: I've cropped your photo - primarily for the black bars, but you also had a packing slip visible.  That classes as PII so had to go.

Comment: If you turn the cranks does the chain move through the derailleur OK.Is the chain on the big ring on the crank? if so, change to smaller ring and see what happens.

Comment: I'd check the pivots for stickiness due to grime. Remove the wheel and move the arm front to back.

Comment: You're on a smaller gear at the rear end and your chain is **tight**.  That should not happen, and it's potentially a serious problem, whatever is causing it. If you were to try shifting to a larger gear on the rear now, the chain would try to be even tighter, which won't end well. I don't see how it can be a problem with the derailleur - something else is pulling the chain tight - which doesn't really make any sense. Check the chain - where is it?  Post pictures that show the entire chain - where it's sitting, what gear(s) it's on.

Comment: Does Acera have offset jockey wheels? To me, it looks like the guide pulley is missing. There’s also what looks like a bend midway on the derailleur cage, although that may be intentional as well.

Comment: Try removing the wheel again and see if the derailleur can pivot around the mounting bolt. In the photo, that pivot seems to be rotated too far clockwise, which is why juhist suggests the possibility of a broken spring. I also think you may be missing the B-link; the derailleur in a more “normal” position would be awfully forwards.

Comment: I would guess that a spring has popped loose in the derailer.

Comment: Can you please post a photo of the front part of your drivetrain?

Comment: Could it be that the chain wheel is pushed into the wrong part of the chain?

Comment: We can't see from the photo how the chain passes around the chainwheel(s).  This chain can't possibly be long enough for this bike because it could not possibly allow the rear derailleur to move the chain up to any of the yet larger sprockets.  If you were riding the bike, stopped, removed the rear wheel and replaced it, you must have tangled the chain up in the chainwheel, front derailleur or have it around the bottom bracket shell somehow.  Compare the chain path of your bike now with another bike that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: imho @MaplePanda has a point, the guide pulley wheel seems to be missing. Probably also worth checking, if the nose on the bracket still fits into the hanger or slid by somehow because the hanger or the bracket got bent.

Comment: Its been a couple of months, how have you got on with this ?  Did you fix it?  Please do post an answer showing what the cause was.

Comment: @SilentMotion For reference, this appears to be a [Shimano RD-M390](https://alaskabicyclecenter.com/products/shimano-acera-m390-sgs-9-speed-long-cage-rear-derailleur).  The guide (jockey) pulley is mounted very high up, and at that angle would be hidden behind the parallelogram; the visible shoulder of the inner cage plate is well away from the hidden pulley.

Comment: Assuming that there's no slack in the chain, I'd say the chain is just too short! How would the bike shift onto a larger cog?

Comment: @DimaTisnek - There's plenty of slack in the chain.

Comment: Then I have to agree with Daniel, the spring is busted. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74771/11260 (or the joint is stuck due to dirt, etc)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. The way Shimano imagined it.*

It looks like you have the first link of the mechanism mounted 90° clockwise. Try again.

Comment: Why would he have removed the derailer while changing a tire?

Comment: That upper pivot is sprung to rotate the derailleur counterclockwise. Perhaps the spring got dislodged, allowing the derailleur to rotate to its current more clockwise position.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly a spring has popped loose in the derailer.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the chain.

When you put it back bring the chain above the gear.

Put the chain under the second gear then put the chain back together.

It should fix it, or the spring is broken, or the spring popped loose.

Comment: The chain is properly routed.

Comment: i see the chain not on the gear

Comment: people take off the wheel to change the popped innertube faster

Comment: Taking the wheel off would not change the routing of the chain through the derailer.